# Redeclaration allowed?

Tags: c++

I found a weird bug (if that's a bug actually). You can redeclare a variable later in the same scope, while you can already use the first same named variable. Is that normal?

This code compiles and works without any error/warning. I am compiling with g++ using Code Blocks.

```
int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    if(1)
        int test = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the same scope. Scope isn't simply "count the `{` and `}`s".

Comment: Oh well, my bad. But is this normal? This isn't a bug at all, or is it? I mean, I can understand if you declare them in another function, but right here, you still have access to the first variable. How and why is this allowed?

Comment: yes. It is normal.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
if(1)
    int test = 0;
```

is equal to:

```
if(1){
    int test = 0;
}
```

So it is scoped part. and the `test` inside the `if` is not the same as the one outside the scope.

You can **NOT** access the outer `test` variable.

```
int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    if(1){
        int test = 5;
        std::cout << "Inner:" << test<< "\n";
        //you can not access the outer test 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but you still have access to the first variable while the second one is getting redeclared...

Answer (score 3):

Try the following to see that the `if` created a new scope:

```
int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    if(1)
        int test = 1;
    cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

So this is not a bug, it is per [specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

Answer (score 2):

They're not in the same scope. That you didn't put curly braces around a single statement (rather than compound) *statement_true* doesn't mean that the `if` doesn't create a new scope.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: Well, I know that if you don't put braces, only the next line is read as if there are braces. What I couldn't understand is a redeclaration without warning. But anyway, I got my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard allows same named variables to exist in different scopes and it defines the rules as to which variable will be referenced when you use them inside a scope. Same named variables will hide(shadow) the variables at higher level scope.

L.E: [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)